A politician says america isn't the best country
Four or five months ago, I have seen a video on facebook, it had over half million shares and thousands of likes. On the captions, it said it is a part of a series, however I can't find the video anymore.
I clearly remember the video very well, if someone could identify it for me, it would lead to the series.
In the video, college students sit in a large auditorium with some politicians and an interviewer. 
Everything goes well in the interview besides a politician who got satirical and joked over the question.
Until someone asked him:

Why is America the best country in the whole world?

He jokes too, but the interviewer wouldn't accept his joke, so he was forced to answer his question.
The video shows you later a girl who holds a flashcard from the college crowed saying:
 IT'S NOT. 

Then, the politician explodes and says American isn't the greatest country in the world, and goes on with a very inspirational and moving speech, it was extremely well executed, and perfect acting (that I thought the interview was real when I first watched it).
It was stuck in my memory. Someone must have seen it.

This is The Newsroom from 2012. Note that the character (Will McAvoy) is a newscaster, not a politician




Why is SE saying you answered on Jan 2 when I asked this yesterday, stackexchange is getting weirder day by day...
